# Как использовать Асинхронные методы в Moxy?

Tags: java, android, mvp, moxy

У меня есть `Activity` там `presenter`. Есть еще `GoogleMaps`. У карты есть метод `getMapsAsync`. Так как нужно время чтобы карты гугл стали готовы. Также как у `MediaPlayer prepare`.

После создания активити и поворота используется `getViewState` и вызывается некий метод сразу же после переворота, когда Карты гугл еще не успели создастя. В итоге я получаю `NullPointer`.

Как решается такая проблема в Moxy?

---

Я только могу предположить что нужно как  - то сделать задержку в вызове getViewState чтобы карты гугл создались....Но как, это же надо Moxy переписывать, может это и не правильно...

Comment: ох, там вообще не понятно:D лучше реализовывать самому MVP паттерн и не париться:D

Comment: https://gist.github.com/terrakok/cd080a6a0213ef7430bdd72ebe92c9ef

Comment: как и сказал @post_zeew, в данном случае необходимо использовать MvpDelegate